# worksheets name as seeked value for Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, worksheet-function

For my sending email macro, I would like to use vlookup where seeked value is the tabs name. By  using tabs name I would get an email address from one of the worksheets. Unfortunately, my code is not working:

```
Sub znajdzadres()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim eadr As Variant
Dim nameW As Variant
nameW = ws.Name

eadr = "Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([nameW],DOSTAWCY!R2C1:R83C3,3,0)"




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quote the formula when applying a worksheet function and apply the string var as-is with the appropriate worksheet/range reference.

```
Dim eadr As Variant
Dim nameW As Variant

nameW = ActiveSheet.Name

eadr = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(nameW, worksheets("DOSTAWCY").range("A2:C83"), 3, 0)

debug.print eadr
```

Comment: Could u elaborate please?     @Jeeped                                                                               
    Sub znajdzadres()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim eadr As Variant
Dim nameW As Variant
nameW = ActiveSheet.Name

eadr = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(nameW, DOSTAWCY!R2C1:R83C3, 3, 0)
Debug.Print eadr




End Sub

Comment: Yes, the worksheet and range shouldn't have been left as worksheet formula syntax; I've updated.

Comment: Runtime 91  now. Asking for nameW debug

Comment: Works fine for me once I create a worksheet named DOSTAWCY with a table containing the active worksheet name in column A.

Comment: Sows NameW as empty and cant proceed forward

Comment: I take iT back , works like a charm!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU @Jeeped